Approximating the temperature of the wall of the heating jack of a reactor
Suppose we have a reactor containing some fluid that we heat through a heating jacket containing some other fluid.
I am interested in approximating the temperature of the wall of heating jacket. I believe that the arithmetic mean of the mean temperatures of the two fluids is a good approximation, but I do not know how to justify this or any references on this topic. So, my question is this: is my idea good and if yes, could you please provide me a reference supporting this? If not, what is the best approach in this generic case?

The heat equation for a material region that's not itself generating heat is
$$\rho c\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T),$$
with density $\rho$, specific heat capacity $c$, temperature $T$, time $t$, and thermal conductivity $k$. Broadly, this means that the larger the local temperature difference from the surroundings is, the faster the region tends to change temperature to match the surroundings.
If the thermal conductivity is constant (e.g., temperature-independent), then $k$ can be brought out to give
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha\nabla^2 T,$$
where $\alpha\equiv\frac{k}{\rho c}$ is the thermal diffusivity and $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian; the 1D version is the second derivative $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$. The straightforward interpretation is that curvatures in temperature profiles tend to straighten out over time.
If things aren't changing fast temporally, then we might make the approximation $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= 0$ (steady state). The solution to the above equation is now $T(x)=T_{\mathrm{wall,}1}+\frac{T_{\mathrm{wall,}2}-T_{\mathrm{wall,}1}}{L}x$, where $T_\mathrm{wall}$ represents the wall temperatures and $L$ is the wall thickness.
So the simplest single representation of the wall temperature under these conditions is the arithmetic mean of the surface temperatures. However, the surface temperatures don't necessarily equal the adjacent fluid temperatures. The temperature profile at steady state looks like this:

(Incropera & DeWitt, Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer)
In other words, the surface temperatures are mediated by both the adjacent fluid temperatures and the convection coefficient $h$ of heat transfer with the fluid. These convection coefficients can be different on either side, as they depend on the fluid, fluid speed, and surface roughness, among other parameters.
Putting this together, the wall temperature expressed as a single number is
$$\frac{T_{\mathrm{wall,}1}+T_{\mathrm{wall,}2}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left[T_{\mathrm{fluid,}1}\left(1-\frac{1}{h_1R}+\frac{1}{h_2R}\right)+T_{\mathrm{fluid,}2}\left(1+\frac{1}{h_1R}-\frac{1}{h_2R}\right)\right],$$
where $R=\frac{1}{h_1}+\frac{L}{k}+\frac{1}{h_2}$. (Verify that this algebra is correct.) If the convection coefficients are nearly the same, this is essentially just $\frac{T_{\mathrm{fluid,}1}+T_{\mathrm{fluid,}2}}{2}$—the arithmetic mean again. But this last expression could give misleading predictions if the fluid flow is slow on one side and fast on the other side, for example, or if the fluids are different. (Example: I could expose my bare chest to still air at -40°C and not fear frostbite, even though the average temperature of air and blood is less than 0°C. My capillaries are good at convecting heat into my epidermis, and quiescent air is poor at removing it. I use my chest here as a simple example because the tissue underneath is at nearly physiological temperature, unlike my extremities. Indeed, if $h_1\to 0$, verify that the wall temperature approaches $T_{\mathrm{fluid,}2}$.)

Thank you very much for your explanations! In the heating jacket I have steam at $150^\circ$ C and in the continuous stirred-tank reactor I have water at $20^\circ$ C that must be heated to $121^\circ$ C. By computing the temperature of the wall using the arithmetic mean formula that I mentioned, I obtained a temperature that is close to the fluid in the reactor (namely $110^\circ$ C). Do you think thay my setting fitts the theoretical framework that you described? I just want to make sure that I got everything right.

That strikes me as a case where the convection coefficients $h$ could be quite different on either side.

Okay, I understand. I tried to determine the partial heat transfer coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ through an iterative procedure based on the fact that the specific heat flow depends in an approximately linear way on temperature on a small enough interval. I obtained values that are not within the bounds in the book by Pavlov, Romankov and Noskov: $\alpha_1\in (9300, 15000) \frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2 \text{K}}$ and $\alpha_2 \in (1500, 7000) \frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2 \text{K}}$. The global coefficient that I obtained is around $1000\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2 \text{K}}$. ...

... What method would you recommend to find these coefficients and implicitly the temperatures?

Some options are to (1) check textbooks and handbooks that discuss heat exchangers, such as the text mentioned above and Perry's Chemical Engineer Handbook, for example, (2) describe your specific setup in Engineering Stack Exchange, which is focused more on practical implementation, and (3) actually measure the temperature, since that takes precedence over modeling.
